# Converting between long and short data.frame formats

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

Simple (?) `tidyr` question:

I have a `data.frame` which has several grouping columns and several value columns, in long format. I want to convert it to short (wide) format, where the `key` would be one of the grouping columns and the resulting `data.frame` would have a column for each combination of all the other grouping columns and each of the value columns.

Here's my long-format `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(treatment = rep(c(rep("T1",3),rep("T2",3)),2),
                 species = c(rep("S1",6),rep("S2",6)),
                 group = rep(LETTERS[1:3],4),
                 n = as.integer(runif(12,10,20))) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(treatment,species) %>% dplyr::mutate(freq = n/sum(n))
```

And here's what I want the resulting wide-format `data.frame` to be:

```
res.df <- data.frame(group = LETTERS[1:3],
                     T1.S1.n = dplyr::filter(df,treatment == "T1",species == "S1")$n,
                     T1.S1.freq = dplyr::filter(df,treatment == "T1",species == "S1")$freq,
                     T2.S1.n = dplyr::filter(df,treatment == "T2",species == "S1")$n,
                     T2.S1.freq = dplyr::filter(df,treatment == "T2",species == "S1")$freq,
                     T1.S2.n = dplyr::filter(df,treatment == "T1",species == "S2")$n,
                     T1.S2.freq = dplyr::filter(df,treatment == "T1",species == "S2")$freq,
                     T2.S2.n = dplyr::filter(df,treatment == "T2",species == "S2")$n,
                     T2.S2.freq = dplyr::filter(df,treatment == "T2",species == "S2")$freq)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `gather` to convert to 'long' format, then `unite` the columns together and `spread` to 'wide'

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df, key, val, n:freq) %>% 
     unite(trtsp, treatment, species, key, sep = ".") %>%
     spread(trtsp, val)
```